# Why does setting the UITableView datasource on a popover in storyboard results in my app crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I basically just set up the table view so I can see how it looks. I've set the protocols in the header file as well.

Here is the code

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using iOS6? Because only in iOS 6 will dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier always give you a cell. In iOS5 you have to check that you have a cell and if it is nil init a cell.

Comment: yes using ios 6. Not supporting ios 5 because of collection views and auto layout and with ios 7 coming out soon.